# SQL Server 2008: is there a way to avoid writing to transaction log?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

Although my query is correct, I will intermittently get this error. Is there a way to avoid writing to transaction log?

When I checked the specified column, each column's text read: "Nothing"

**The Error:**

> The transaction log for database
>   'tempdb' is full. To find out why
>   space in the log cannot be reused, see
>   the log_reuse_wait_desc column in
>   sys.databases".

Thanks, greatly appreciated, somewhat urgent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You need to use the transaction log.**  It's how SQL rolls back in case of an error or partial completion of a query.

The root cause is not the transaction log, it's the query.  You either:

**1** - Have a poorly optimized query (lots of sorts or hash joins can cause this)

**2** - Are overusing #temp tables in your query

**3** - Have a drive space issue

Can you post the query you are running?

**EDIT:**

To clarify what could be causing the issue...

If  you have multiple `#temp` tables, they all take up space in tempdb.  Any sorting that the query engine has to do
**(`ORDER BY` without an index, complicated `JOIN` conditions that don't use indexes, lots of `GROUP BY`, or aggregate functions, etc)**
writes to the transaction log for `tempdb` because all that sorting is done there.

The query itself may **function** fine but it probably needs to be optimized to avoid these issues.

Comment: The query itself is fine, I am just processing 18Mil Records

Comment: @William - if the query itself were fine you could process 18m records without a tempdb overrun.  I process 700m records every month for one dataset and don't have this issue.

Comment: The query is using no joins, however, it does use a cursor

Comment: @William - you will find that cursors are almost universally reviled because of their poor performance.  If you want help optimizing this to not use a cursor I think you could probably find some help, were you to open a new question.

Comment: I am open to this and will repost as a new question.

Comment: Depending on the cursor options it might store the whole resultset in `tempdb`.

Answer (score 1):

No, EVERY transaction gets logged. However, this is not a problem with logging.

It states the tempdb is full, not your log file. Are you processing a lot of records? Using temp table?

You need to manage the growth in the sense that you may need to do batches and commit more often.

Comment: @William - post your table structure and query please.

Comment: @William, how much disk space do you have for your tempdb files?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server uses transaction logs to keep track of what its doing, there is no way to avoid this (nor would you want to, for many, many reasons). The issue is here is this:

- temdb is a system DB in sql server that sql server uses to write temp data, such as cached data for really long queries, and temp tables (any tables created with #, ## as the prefix).
- when you first installed the sql server, it created the tempdb on the drive all the data is on.
- when you run a query that does temp tables, or is long running, the cached data is written in tempdb - when it does that, it also inherently uses the transaction log of the tempdb.

In your case, the log file of the DB gets filled up probably because there is too much data being cached/written to tempdb, and the drive that tempdb log file is probably full. You should have 'shrink automatically' option 'on' for your tempdb, and to fix this problem easily, you can restart sql services, and it will automatically eliminate the extra data in the log file for tempdb.

You could try to tune your query a little bit, so it doesn't have to write too much data to the tempdb (eliminate long result sets. avoid #temptables, etc)

Comment: `'shrink automatically' option 'on' ` is **not** a good practice on any database including `tempdb`

Comment: Its a failsafe when there are other factors leading to an expanded tempdb. When the tempdb grows, the entire performance of the DB goes down exponentially. Having a shrink automatically on helps to keep the rest of the transactions performing smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Just to validate the tempdb problem, in your JOINS, force LOOP join ex:
select * from test
inner LOOP join
test2
on x=y

AND remove all ORDER BY clauses.

If the query runs without filling your tempdb (but may be a lot slower) then you know that hash (or sorting) is required and using too much tempdb space.

It may requires good query analysis to fix that, but check the execution plan and try to do everything possible to remove any sorting or hash join, if possible by creating index(es) or sometimes forcing join type (but normally if statistics are good you should do that only as the last possibility).

Good luck